# How can i install the drivers of a smartphone with processor mtk 6589 for Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, driver, smartphone

I'm programming Android with Eclipse, but when trying to execute my app eclipse recognizes the smartphone, but he can't use it to test the app.In the device selection apears rare characters.
The ok button is disabled. I know that is a driver problem, but search for mtk 6589 drivers for Linux and i can't found nothing.

Here an image:
[image]

Comment: Did you add this vendor to /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up).

1) Log in as root and create this file:  `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` (if doesn't exists).

2) `chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules after creation`

3) open for edit with any editor(nano for example): `sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

4) Add vendor like: `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`
where 0bb4 - id of your device vedor

[Vendor IDs can take here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html).

Comment: I have not idea for how know the vendor.

Comment: @DanielRuiz i updated answer. You can get ID by going to link

Comment: I saw for MTK is 0e8d. When I have a moment I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: I tried with your answer and after reboot eclipse. But the problem persists. The code in my 51-android.rules file is SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="Oe8d", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

Comment: 0e8d, not Oe8d...SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0e8d", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

Comment: Sorry, i wanted to say zero. SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0e8d", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
I restart the system but the problem persists.